# How can I tell Spring to create more database connections when maxActive is reached?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app with below database pool settings. If the app continuously runs for 2 to 3 days, I get pool empty error. So, 2 questions regarding this,

1. I really suspect connection leaks might have happened. No. of users for our application is very less, so 32 should not be exhausted for our user base. How can I find leaked connections?
2. If I want to tell Spring to create few more connections when maxActive(32 in my case) is reached, what is the setting needs to be added?

   ```
   poolProperties.setTestOnBorrow(true);
   poolProperties.setTestOnConnect(true);
   poolProperties.setTestWhileIdle(true);
   poolProperties.setInitialSize(10);
   poolProperties.setMinIdle(10);
   poolProperties.setMaxIdle(10);
   poolProperties.setMaxActive(32);
   poolProperties.setMaxWait(5000); //5 secs
   poolProperties.setLogValidationErrors(true);
   poolProperties.setLogAbandoned(true);
   poolProperties.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
   ```

`o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(129) - [http-nio-6061-exec-9] Timeout: Pool empty. Unable to fetch a connection in 5 seconds, none available[size:32; busy:32; idle:0; lastwait:5000]`

Comment: Max active is the **maximum active** number. If you want to increase it, change `32` to `35`.... that would give you three more. As for leaked connections, check your logs.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Won't it be better to create new connections only when all the existing 32 are busy?

Comment: That is how the pool works already. All 32 are busy. Hence "Unable to fetch a connection in 5 seconds, none available[size:32; busy:32; idle:0; lastwait:5000]"